# spring and angular2 how to request the post data with params?

Tags: spring, angular

angular2 how request the data with the params,and spring `@requestParam` or `@requestBody` like this..

```
/**
 * 后台账户登录
 *
 * @param userName userName
 * @param password password
 * @return result
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public AdminModel login(@RequestParam String userName, @RequestParam String password) {
    AdminModel adminModel = service.findAdminUserByUserName(userName);
    if (adminModel == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (MD5Util.encode(password, adminModel.getSalt()).equals(adminModel.getPassword())) {
        return null;
    }
    return adminModel;
}
```

I have tried many times,but I can't get the correct method.

Comment: Whats your angular code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`URLSearchParams`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html). This will automatically set the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and encode the params into the correct format.

```
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('userName', userName);
params.set('password', password);

this.http.post(url, params)
```